# How to see which projects/why failed to build VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

Simple question , after build i have the following :

```
========== Build: 68 succeeded, 5 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now , i do not have any errors(which means my error list in VS shows 0 errors) , how do i know which projects and why fail to build ?

[image]

Comment: The errors are written in the 'errors' console. If you dont see it, check "View" menu where the display setting should be

Comment: Have you looked under `View -> error list`?

Comment: i wrote i dont have any errors , that include in the errors list obviously.

Comment: Did you check the errors panel? It shows you each error, and from which project it was originated.

Comment: `5 failed` - That means that you **must have errors** somewhere. Check the errors view under `view`.

Comment: @KobyDouek i probably have , but how can i find them , when like i said my error list is empty(0 errors)

Comment: @ChrisTanev - Are you **sure** you did not **filter out** the errors by clicking on the errors icon ?

Comment: Are you using Resharper Build?

Comment: i added picture , if it helps . @zaitsman no i use Visual studio build/i didnt enable the resharper build

Comment: @ChrisTanev Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911433/visual-studio-2015-project-builds-failed-but-no-errors

Answer (score 2):

Yeah VS 2015 doesn't show errors at times or show errors that were already fixed.I don't know why. Our solution also had around 70 projects
So What i used to do was to check the Build Log in Output tab. This will have the log of each project including errors if any. Or do MsBuild from Msbuild command prompt of VS 2015. Easy to identify the issue.

Comment: yea i was trying to find something in the output and I looked for `error` and i found 2 error only in Release build :  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: MCG0024:UnresolvableTypeReference Unresolvable type reference 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef' in 'Assembly(Name=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.
`