# Visual Studio Build Fails When Changing Timezone

Tags: visual-studio

So, this relates to one of the "Answers" on [Visual Studio 2015 project builds failed but no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911433/visual-studio-2015-project-builds-failed-but-no-errors) that explains that this happens when the timezone changes.

Why does visual studio fail a build with zero errors when you change the timezone on your machine?  Sure you can close and re-open the application, then re-load the solution, but this is not a feasible solution.