# Where to find microsoft.mshtml.dll on docker image

Tags: windows, docker, build-tools, build-server

In my build server docker image based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809-amd64, I get a missing reference error to microsoft.mshtml.dll while running the build. The dll is related to the internet explorer which is clearly not installed on that image. I have dotnet framework 4.7.2 SDK and TargetingPack installed on the image, which do not seem to include the file. Is there a SDK or a workload of the visual studio build tools which contains this dll? Is there a way figure out which workload/sdk contains which files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the workloads and components that can be installed with Visual Studio Build Tools as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools), the dll is contained in *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TeamOffice.BuildTools*.

Comment: I am asking myself how you figured out that this workload contains this (among a ton of other components) library, but yes, after installing this, i could build my stuff again. Thanks!